# How to use credentials to access Google Cloud information for other users

Tags: google-api, google-cloud-platform, google-oauth, google-authentication

I've been crawling the web but haven't been able to figure this out.

I want to write an app with the following behavior: it presents existing users of Google Cloud with a login window to which they enter their Cloud credentials - user and password. With those credentials, I want to programmatically access and fetch their respective billing data so I can later display it to them. This should obviously be able to serve multiple users.

I don't understand how to get past the very first step, which is - what do I do after I get the credentials? Is there a client library method to which I supply them and then gain access to the user's info?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Firebase Authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/) or [Google Identity Toolkit](https://developers.google.com/identity/toolkit/web/), see sample [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/reference)